# Launching Chrome (Incognito Mode) From Terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, google-chrome

I am trying to create a mirror image of Chrome-OS on an Ubuntu installation starting with shortcuts. On Chrome-OS,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>N</kbd>   will bring up an incognito mode of Chrome. The problem implementing this shortcut is that I don't know  if there is a command to open an incognito mode of Chrome. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For Chromium

```
chromium-browser --incognito
```

For Google-chrome

```
 google-chrome --incognito
```

Note:  get used to see `man` for cli options, in this case `man chromium-browser` or `man google-chrome`

Comment: @DavidCole, get used to see `man` for cli options, in this case `man chromium-browser` or `man google-chrome`

Answer (score 2):

For Brave browser

```
brave-browser --incognito
```

For Firefox

```
firefox -private-window
```

For Google chrome

```
 google-chrome --incognito
```

For chromium

```
chromium-browser --incognito
```

Comment: The part of this answer that gives the solution to the quesiton asked is an exact duplicate of the top and accepted answer.  The additional information added in this answer is not related to the question that was asked.

Comment: Many web developers use firefox or firefox developer edition, which makes this answer precise to the point