# Unable to launch Chrome even from the terminal

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

When I type google-chrome in the terminal, I get:

> [21143:21143:0728/071120.789639:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(279)] Failed to create /home/subham/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: File exists
>   [21143:21143:0728/071120.789834:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1550)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
>   [21143:21177:0728/071120.822974:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(103)] Failed to launch GPU process.

Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't solve the problem. What to do

Comment: You should be able to install Chrome using the Ubuntu Software tool which is the preferred method.  Failing that you  can find your answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/688295/launching-chrome-incognito-mode-from-terminal?rq=1

Comment: @jones0610 Chrome is not available in the Ubuntu Software

Comment: Sure it is.  At Least it's in 16.04 LTS.  Ubuntu Software-> Internet->Web Browsers

Comment: What happens if you run Chrome after this command: `mv /home/subham/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock /home/subham/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock.bak` ? Don't forget to start your comments with @Raphael if you are replying to me, otherwise I might miss them.

Comment: @jones0610 are you referring to the chromium browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't want to start because the lock file exists.

1. Be sure every process of google-chrome are killed :
   `sudo killall google-chrome`
2. Delete lockFile or even the the .config/google-chrome folder.  It will be re-create when the app will start.
   `rm /home/subham/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock`
3. Start google-chrome